# where can i find some android web page templates, css or html to use as a starter page

Tags: html, css, android, themes

In searching the web I came across http://groupaware.mobi/iphone which
has a sample iphone navigation site.

Is there someplace I can find a similar thing for android? i.e.
sample web pages with css, sample templates, navigation etc.

If not, what suggestions would you have to offer to someone looking
to build a web page for android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the second, take a look at http://m.kozlenko.info/#Android which lists websites optimised for various mobiles. The first one, Android Network Awards will provide you with a lot of tips.

Comment: welcome @C. Papadopoulos, it helps if you put your additional answers as edits to the first one..

Comment: Thank you, I know but there was a limitation at the time on how many hyperlinks my post could contain.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want your website to look and animate like the Android UI or just be displayed correctly in the browser?
If the first is what you have in mind, I think the sample applications in http://www.codestrong.com/timobile/guides/android/ui/windows/ will help you.